# Discriminated Union with Integer Values in F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to compose an F# type that would have the following signature:

```
type Foo = (Distance * Event * Course)
```

So that you would create a Foo like this:

```
let bar = (25, Freestyle, LCM)
```

Now the second two parts (event and course) are easy–I'm sure that distance is also, I just don't know it yet–I just use a discriminated union.

Let's say that the only valid values for distance are [25;50;100], what is the best way to construct the Distance type?

Comment: `type Distance = TwentyFive | Fifty | Hundred`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the goal is to have easy access to a real integer value, but restrict it to only a set number of cases.

@Petr's suggestion would work fine, you would just convert the enum value to int.

Another option is to calculate the value in a method on a DU type:

```
type Distance = 
    TwentyFive | Fifty | Hundred
    member this.ToInt() =
        match this with
        | TwentyFive -> 25
        | Fifty -> 50
        | Hundred -> 100
```

or if you want stronger syntax support, a single-case active pattern might be nice:

```
type Event = Freestyle | Backstroke
type Distance = TwentyFive | Fifty | Hundred
let (|IntDistance|) d =
    match d with
    | TwentyFive -> 25
    | Fifty -> 50
    | Hundred -> 100

let race = (Fifty, Freestyle)

let (IntDistance(dist), evt) = race
printfn "Race info: %d %A" dist evt

match race with
| IntDistance(dist), Freestyle -> ...
| IntDistance(dist), Backstroke -> ...
```

Comment: It might be worth considering floats with units of measure instead of ints for the numeric distances. *I deleted my answer and replaced it with this comment, since it was a few seconds too late and barely different to this answer's first code block – except that it used floats annotated with meters from* `Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitSymbols`.

Comment: No guarantee that the units will be meters, they could be yards. The course member determines unit of measure.

Comment: It's not so much that I want easy access to an integer value, although that helps. To keep in sync with the ubiquitous language of the domain, an event would be "25 Free LCM", where "LCM' means "Long Course Meters", so I think the type constructor needs to take in the integer value rather than "TwentyFive".

Does that help?

Comment: Units of measure can be generic, so they are still potentially useful here

Comment: If you want to type system to enforce the set of valid distances at compile-time, you'll need to use a union, as suggested.  Otherwise, you'd need to define a class which takes the number as a constructor argument, and validates it at runtime.

Comment: Will go with the runtime validation, thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET enums:

```
type Distance = TwentyFive=25 | Fifty=50 | Hundred=100
```

For pattern matching you must use qualified name though: `Distance.Fifty`